# Parameter set cannot be resolved using the specified named parameters in powershell

Tags: azure

I am trying to delete session hosts in the host pool in the AVD Environment but it is throwing error

> Parameter set cannot be resolved using the specified named parameters.

Command:

```
Remove-AzWvdUserSession -ResourceGroupName $env:RGName -HostPoolName $env:HostPoolName -SessionHostName $currentVMName -Id $sessionid -Force
```

Answer (score 0):

To delete the Azure virtual desktop, make use of below modified script:

Created host pool with session host like below:

[image]

To delete the session host, make use of below command:

[image]

```c
# Replace with your own values
$resourceGroupName = "RGName"  
$hostPoolName = "poolName"
$sessionHostName = "SessionHostName"

# Remove the session host
Remove-AzWvdSessionHost -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName -HostPoolName $hostPoolName -SessionHostName $sessionHostName
```

To confirm in portal session host removed successfully like below:

[image]